# Using TRIM in Google Sheet Query

Tags: sql, google-sheets

I have this QUERY

`QUERY(Z:AA,"Select AA where UPPER(Z) matches '"&trim($U3)&"'",0)`

but its not working for some reason which I can't understand. If the match I'm looking for is `redapple` and the contents of U3 is `red apple` the match fails. Setting U3 to `redapple` matches so it appears `TRIM` is not working.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

My Bad. `TRIM` only removes trailing and leading spaces. Used `SUBSTITUTE` instead